# Sample problems on logit modeling and Bayesian methods

Tags: modeling, bayesian, logit, transportation

I'm looking for worked out solutions using Bayesian and/or logit analysis similar to a workbook or an annal.

The worked out problems could be of any field; however, I'm interested in urban planning / transportation related fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [UCLA Statistical Computing](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/) site has a number of examples in various languages (SAS, R, etc).  In particular, see the following pages (look among the links titled logistic regression, categorical data analysis and generalized linear models):

- [Data Analysis Examples](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/)
- [Textbook Examples](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/default.htm)